# Extended conditions in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I want to have something like a double conditional I want to include in a forloop, in order to reduce computation time I want to do something like the following:

```
for i WHERE i % 2 == 0 in range(0,(realbignumber/2)):
    if i % realbignum == 0: do some stuff
```

I am mostly uncertain on the proper way to do that 'where' type statement in the forloop? I'm sure there are probably better approaches to take to reduce computation time (i'm trying to do a prime factorization of realbignum) and will start by getting a list of divisors, then check for primeness. Once I get the i%2==0 'where' clause figured out I plan on implementing something like 'for i where i is prime in range....do stuff. I'm working in python 2 but am fine with python 3 approaches as well.

Comment: as you are trying to do a prime factorization, take a look at this: [how to implement an efficient infinite generator of prime numbers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator expression, like this

```
for i in (num for num in xrange(realbignumber / 2) if num % 2 == 0):
```

For this particular case, you can actually specify the `step` argument in [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) itself, like this

```
for i in xrange(0, realbignumber / 2, 2):
```

Please note that I have used `xrange` instead of `range` function. Because `range` function in Python 2.x create a list of numbers, where as `xrange` creates just an [`xrange` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange). So `xrange` is suitable for very long ranges, as it is highly memory efficient.

---

If the input number is too big to fit in Python's int, then you can roll your own simplified range function, with the help of generators, like this

```
>>> def my_range(start, stop, step=1):
...     current = start
...     while current < stop:
...         yield current
...         current += step
... 
>>> [num for num in my_range(0, 10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or you can use the `itertools` version, shown by the ShadowRanger, like this

```
>>> from itertools import islice, count
>>> def bigxrange(start, stop, step=1):
...     return islice(count(start, step), (stop - start + step - 1))
... 
>>> list(bigxrange(0, 10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately my number is too big for xrange, I'm getting "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" Any idea on getting around that? -- I'm aware that this likely won't compute in a suitable time, I'm currently attempting to watch output as it goes to make sure things are working as expected and will then work on optimizing, still new to this code thing =)

Comment: @Abraxas You can use the generator function, like I have shown in the updated answer.

Comment: @Abraxas: No good workaround. Best you can do is build a `bigxrange` from `itertools` parts: `from itertools import islice, count`, `def bigxrange(start, stop, step=1): return islice(count(start, step), (stop - start + step - 1) // step)`

Comment: Thanks guys! Output is flying across the screen now. =D

Comment: @thefourtheye: The `itertools` approach is likely to be much closer to the speed of `xrange` by pushing all the work to C.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree. Thanks for pointing it out :-) I included that also in the answer.

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue with the bigxrange implementation, I have this line: for i in bigxrange(0, (thenum / 2), 2): based on the code provided in the definition in the answer but I am receiving: ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= maxint.

Comment: @Abraxas Hmmm, then you can settle with the `my_range` implementation or switch to Python 3, where this int restriction is not there :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114088/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long) can help you.

With python3, according to [this discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue21816#msg221121) and this [python3 documentation reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), that code should work.