# Python Overflow error: int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner and I'm doing the problems in  and while doing the third problem, which is about finding the largest prime factor of 600851475143, I get this error:

Python int too large to convert to C long

```
plist = [2]


def primes(min, max):
    if 2 >= min:
        yield 2
    for i in xrange(3, max, 2):
        for p in plist:
            if i % p == 0 or p * p > i:
                break
        if i % p:
            plist.append(i)
            if i >= min:
                yield i


def factors(number):
    for prime in primes(2, number):
        if number % prime == 0:
            number /= prime
            yield prime
        if number == 1:
            break

a = 600851475143
print max(factors(a))
```

Comment: Where do you convert to a `long`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverflowError Python int too large to convert to C long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114088/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long)

Comment: I don't, I'm using Windows PowerShell to run that script, and the error shown is in that itself

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think they don't, `xrange` apparently does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly, in Python 2, `xrange` requires its arguments to fit into a C `long`. `600851475143` is too big for that on your system. You'll have to rewrite your algorithm to not need such a big range, or use a substitute, such as your own `xrange` implementation, or a `while` loop with manual counter management.

Answer (score -1):

This occurs when the number you are dealing with is greater than `sys.maxsize`

You could possibly use the numpy module and use a larger data type. Not sure how large you need without checking though.

Comment: How to do it without numpy dependency?